# "JNDI lookup to retrieve local XU failed" diagnostics warning for Business Rules Service on Bluemix

Tags: business-rules, ibm-cloud

I ran the Diagnostics on the Rule Execution Server console, and I saw the message

`Local XU connectivity

 Warning    JNDI lookup to retrieve local XU failed.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this warning is expected when running the Diagnostics, and it is safe to ignore it.